# onbeforeunload working for first time in firefox,in IE in the beginning itself alert coming.how to reslove this

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I am trying to add on before unloading in app.js, but this is not working as I expected.in chrome working fine, but in FF and IE not working, not working means in FF after refreshing alert is not coming,
in IE in the login page itself alert is coming

```
                if(SessionStorage.getVal("hasRole") != null ){
                     if(AuthService.getRole() == 'staff'){  
                        $window.onbeforeunload  = function(){
                           return 'are you sure you want to leave this page?';
                         } 
                      }
```